# Does $\sum_{n=2}^ \infty \frac 1 {n \sqrt {\ln n}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I want to figure out if this sum converges or diverges: $$\sum_{n=2}^ \infty \frac 1 {n \sqrt {\ln n}}$$

I tried comparing it to the harmonic series, but this is less than that so it was no use. The limit comparison test with the harmonic series doesn't seem to work either, as it gives $\infty$ or $0$. I thought of using the Integral Test, but this doesn't seem to have an obvious integral as far as I can tell.

How should this be done?

Comment: Try the integral test, with the substitution $u=\ln x$.

Comment: Also see Bertrand's series.

Comment: More generally, for any fixed $i$ the series $\sum_n\dfrac1{n\ln n\ln\ln n\ldots(\ln^{(i)}n)^\beta}$ (where $\ln^{(i)}$ denotes the $i$-times-iterated logarithm) converges iff $\beta\gt 1$; this is the case $i=1$.

Comment: The sum $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ does not converge, so your sum surely does not converge either.

Answer (score 4):

By the [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), your series is convergent iff
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $$
is convergent, but obviously that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that it might be of interest to present an approach that relies on pre-calculus tools only.  To that end we proceed.

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{\log(N+1)}&=\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\sqrt{\log(n+1)}-\sqrt{\log(n)}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{\sqrt{\log(n+1)}+\sqrt{\log(n)}}\\\\
&\le \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{2n\sqrt{\log(n)}}
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $\lim_{N\to \infty}\log(N+1)= \infty$, the series of interest diverges.

Comment: @asker Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

With $u = \ln(t)$:

$$\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t\sqrt{\ln(t)}}dt = \int_{\ln(2)}^{\infty}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}} = \int_{\ln(2)}^{\infty}\frac{du}{u^{\frac12}}$$

This diverges because the power is $\frac12 \le 1$.

By integral test, the series diverges.

Comment: Why does it diverge because the power is $\frac 1 2 \le 1$? I'm guessing it has something to do with the rule for p-series, but how do we turn the integral back to a series?

Comment: There's also an error in your notation; the $\infty$ symbol on top of the last two integrals should actually be $\ln (\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \ln n}= \infty$, since $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}[\ln(\ln(x))]=\frac{1}{x \ln x}$.

Notice that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln n}} > \frac{1}{n \ln n} $, hence $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln n}}= \infty $.

Comment: I think your $\frac{1}{\sqrt {n \ln n}}$ should be $\frac{1}{n\sqrt {\ln n}}$.

Comment: @TonyK, thanks! I've edited the answer.

Comment: The same argument, more direct: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(2\sqrt{\ln x}\right)=\frac1{x\sqrt{\ln x}}.$$