# Proof that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln{n}}}$ diverges?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

Probably the best way would be Limit Comparison Test. Intuitively by looking at $a_n$ the sum probably diverges.

However, let's say I choose a $b_n$ in the form $\frac{1}{n^p}$ where $p>1$, which would converge by the p-test. Say, $\frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}}$. Now, I'm supposed to calculate the limit of $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ as n goes to infinity. Hmm, let's see... $\frac{n^\frac{3}{2}}{n\sqrt{\ln{n}}}$... n's cancel out... $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\ln{n}}}$... dang it, looks like we're gonna have to use L'Hospital's rule here... so anyway... $\frac{\frac{1}{2}n^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{1}{2n}(\ln{n})^-\frac{1}{2}}$, cancel the coefficients and simplify the negative exponents... $\frac{n(\ln{n})^{\frac{1}{2}}}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}$, simplify the exponents... $n^{\frac{1}{2}}{(\ln{n})^{\frac{1}{2}}}$... uh-oh, this goes to infinity and our $b_n$ *converges* so Limit Comparison Test is inconclusive...

And when I try using a $b_n$ for which $p<1$, then I just end up with a more complicated fraction with 1 as the numerator, in which case I'm pretty sure L'Hospital wouldn't even be a valid option.

I'm so annoyed whenever logarithms pop up in these convergence-divergence problems and I have a midterm in a couple of days aaaaugh

Comment: I think a useful comparison might be $\sum \frac 1{n\ln n}$...

Comment: Did you try the integral test?

Comment: $p$-series test is NOT enough for this series. This one diverges, yet pretty "slowly"

Comment: @geetha290krm Oh my gosh, I have been underusing the Integral Test during my studies and this is the *archetypical* Integral Test sum... how... (major facepalm)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $\sum_{n=2}^ \infty \frac 1 {n \sqrt {\ln n}}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191027/does-sum-n-2-infty-frac-1-n-sqrt-ln-n-converge) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D2%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5Csqrt%7B%5Cln%7Bn%7D%7D%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 4):

I thought that it might be of interest to present an approach that relies on pre-calculus tools only.  To that end we proceed.

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{\log(N+1)}&=\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\sqrt{\log(n+1)}-\sqrt{\log(n)}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{\sqrt{\log(n+1)}+\sqrt{\log(n)}}\\\\
&\le \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{2n\sqrt{\log(n)}}
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $\lim_{N\to \infty}\log(N+1)= \infty$, the series of interest diverges.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure this is the long way of doing it and the Integral Test is the easier, more streamlined way... ugh

Comment: @josh You think that a couple of steps constitutes the "long way?"  That's interesting.  And as I explicitly stated, this approach uses PRE-CALCULUS tools only.  Do you understand now?